# How to add JavaScript function to be executed after faces-redirect from the Bean in JSF?

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

Is there a way to mark the JavaScript functions added to `RequestContext` (PrimeFaces), to run after a `faces-redirect=true`?

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("myFunction()");
```

Would it have to do by flash, how is it done for messages?

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getFlash().setKeepMessages(true);
```

Preferably, I'd like a method that only wraps the Bean, without adding check in xhtml.
Thanks in advance.

Mojarra 2.1;
PrimeFaces 5.1;
Java 7;

Comment: No I don't think so.  once you "redirect" to another page the execute script stuff is gone.  The executeScript() code I think was meant to execute in AJAX calls and a redirect to a new page is not an Ajax call.

Comment: The page can be opened in several ways, but only from one of them a script must be executed when a given condition is met. So I'd like to do control over the Bean, without the use of `onload`, since, logically, I'd be following a sequence of steps.

Comment: You can't do this in plain http html javascript either without modifying the page that is redirected to. So what you **can do** is put the javascript you want to execute as a string in a flash scoped value and do a `<script>#{myFlashScopedValue}</script>`. Yes it's 'check' but the only solution I see (besides complex things like overriding head/body renderers)

Comment: or add GET parameters to / hash bang the URL and check for that using JS

Answer (score 0):

You can execute it on the `PostConstruct` method of the redirected backing bean, eg:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class RedirectedPage implements Serializable {

    @PostConstruct
    public void postConstruct(){
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("myFunction()");
    }
}
```